# Android : Receive data in UDP/TCP

Tags: android, tcp, udp, wifi

In my Android Application, i have to get data from a Wifi connection (UDP and TCP).

Here is my code for UDP:

```
try {
                // Create new UDP-Socket
                socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT);

                while (isRunning) {

                    byte[] buf = new byte[50];
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf,
                            buf.length);
                    socket.receive(packet);
                    String str = new String(buf, 0, packet.getLength());
                    packet.setLength(buf.length);

                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("getStr", str);
                    msg.setData(b);
                    handler.sendMessage(msg);

                }
```

and for TCP :

```
try {
                s = new Socket(SERVERIP, SERVERPORT);

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

                while (!s.isClosed()) {

                    String strTcp = in.readLine().toString();
                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("getStr", strTcp + "\n");
                    msg.setData(b);

                    handler.sendMessage(msg);

                }
```

It works properly, but my problem is :

My Wifi device send a sequence of data (always the same sequence of string), and when I receive 1250 strings in TCP, i only receive 400 strings in UDP.
Isn't UDP working faster than TCP usually?

I tried the same test on IPhone and it works properly, UDP get as much values as TCP.

So what's the problem? Is the blocking UDP function receive() the problem?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I've tested the code with different devices: UDP works well on Samsung Galaxy Tab (Android 3.1), I receive all datas, but with other devices (Android 4.0) I only receive 1/3 of datas.

Seems to be an hardware problem...

Comment: If you're going to use UDP instead of TCP, you need to implement yourself everything you need that TCP provides and UDP doesn't. Most likely, the major problem in this case is that you didn't implement [transmit pacing, congestion control, and exponential backoff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control).

Comment: When converting bytes to string, and string to bytes, you should use Charset example - new String(text,Charset.defaultCharset());  Maybe that´s the problem? You should use the same charset in both sides.  Another thing, could be string cut in the code for sending strings, can you post your code the sending side?

Comment: "when I receive 1250 strings in TCP, i only receive 400 strings in UDP. Isn't UDP working faster than TCP usually?" yes, correct. But sending via UDP not guarantee the receiver can receive correctly 100%. In this case, TCP should receive better than UDP. Understand? That's why many UDP packets lost. not depend on Mobile hardware actually.

Answer (score 0):

The major difference between TCP and UDP is that TCP is:

> .. provides reliable, ordered delivery of a stream of octets from a
>   program on one computer to another program on another computer.

[Wikipedia - TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)

Whereas UDP:

> .. uses a simple transmission model with a minimum of protocol
>   mechanism.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) It has no handshaking dialogues, and thus exposes any
>   unreliability of the underlying network protocol to the user's
>   program. As this is normally IP over unreliable media, there is no
>   guarantee of delivery, ordering or duplicate protection.

[Wikipedia - UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol)

In otherwords you would have to do implement the handshaking/error-correction yourself if you use UDP/Datagram sockets. Also I notice in your code you allocate a buffer of size 50 to the receiving Datagram socket. If the socket receives data that overflows the buffer it will simply return a full buffer of 50 bytes and ignore the rest; the data that overflows is lost.

when you tried it on the iPhone are you sure that some sort of error-correction is not being done for you behind the scenes? (I have no experience of iPhone development)

Comment: I tested with a size of 100 and 200: same result. This is the format of strings received : $--data*checksum<CR><LF>$--data*checksum<CR><LF>...  Could de receive() function cut the data received at the first <CR><LF> and ignore the rest of data?

Comment: As far as I am aware socket.receive() doesn't discriminate. What's sent is what you get, unless the buffer overflows.